# An OOP pattern that selectively help returns a mathematically-accurate value or its formatted representation

Tags: python, oop, architecture

1. There is an object `trade_pair` whose methods are able to return float values about stored in quotes and values (the number of both currencies, the current price, etc.). Only mathematical float values that are suitable for calculations, but are not suitable for a human and sending to the exchange API (there are requirements for the minimum value, precisions and ticker).

For Example: 
**trade_pair.get_base_value** - is return float `2.43333333333` 
or 
**trade_pair.price** - is return float `51.033452476`

2. On the other hand, there is the logic of formatting float numbers into convenient string values with the desired precision. Such data is suitable for the API, easy for human reading, but not suitable for mathematical operations.

For Example: 
**trade_pair.get_base_value_formatted** - in same time is return str `"2.43300"` (min ticker is 0.001) 
or 
**trade_pair.price_formatted** - is return str `"51.03345"`

How to merge 1 and 2 to OOP pattern without duplication of getters and without function-wrapper like `format(trade_pair.get_base_value)` ..?

Comment: What do you mean by OOP pattern? How will getters be duplicated? The question is not very clear could you please provide a clearer example? Do you want one function to format any string into 5 decimal places?

Comment: @Zingerella I know, how to convert values. Getters in my example can be in two versions: float and string(formatted), but I didn't like this case - lots of extra code. I need patent to create accurate return for each case and each value. I no need algorithm how to convert float to formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

for this `trade_pair` object, If you do not want to write a function to return strings and another to return floats, I suggest merging them by adding a flag. For example:

```
def price(self,formatted=False):
    if formatted: return self.price # returns float
    return str(self.price).format(...) # use whatever conversion method you want
```

This way you can use `trade_pair.price()` for float and `trade_pair.price(True)` or `trade_pair.price(formatted=True)` for strings.